# React responsive modal - animationDuration

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, responsive

I use this modal for my React app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-modal

I cant seem to find out how to use those optional Props. One of them is already used in the example (`center`) which is of type boolean. I would like to use animationDuration prop. How do I set it to my modal and where do I specify the duration?

I have tried few options like using `animationDuration` in `state` or changing the default value of 500ms in the package files but none of this worked for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by putting props in the 'Modal' opening tag.
For Example :

```
<Modal animationDuration={1000} styles={{ modal: { background: "#ccc" } }} closeIconSize={16} open={modalOpen} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center >
     Your modal content here...
</Modal>
```

enjoy!